# Not until [sentence] do [sentence]

Tags: syntactic-analysis, negation, subject-verb-inversion, do-support

Example: “Not until we are lost do we begin to understand ourselves.” – Henry David Thoreau

Can someone explain the structure of the aforementioned sentence?
Can someone name this type of sentence?

Comment: It's a stylised/"literary" re-ordering of the more straightforward *"We **do not** begin to understand ourselves until we are lost"*, so if you understand the structure of the "orginal", you should be able to apply that to the stylised version.

Comment: I do indeed, thank you for the explanation. It was that inversion of “we” and “do” in the middle of the sentence which confused me.

Comment: I can explain the reordering of *we begin to understand ourselves* and *not until we are lost*, but someone else will have to explain why "auxilliary" ***do*** comes between the subject ***we*** and the "primary" verb ***begin***. Something similar happens when statements are converted into questions - *"**I do love** you. **Do you love** me?"*

Comment: Having Italian as my first language, I'm very used to the reordering of sentences and also of parts of the sentence. I've seen the former happening in English before, but this is the first time I stumble upon the latter.

Comment: In your *exact* example I find it impossible to contrive any context where the words "do we" could be reversed. But it's easy to do this with, say *"In rare circumstances **we do** reverse those words"*. Contrary to my orthography there, the heavy stress would fall entirely on the word ***do***, which is only there to emphasize the fact that we do, in case anyone might disagree.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that use as well, but I don't think that this case falls into the same category, hence my question on here. I can find other examples, like a poem by Whitman: http://classiclit.about.com/library/bl-etexts/wwhitman/bl-ww-toprostitute.htm.

Comment: The same "do-insertion + reversal" also occurs naturally after *Not without, Not unless, Not lightly, Not often,* etc. And after ***Only** if/when/where/etc.* So I expect there's some fairly simple rule in play - but being a native speaker I probably just choose the "correct" idiomatic form in any given context without having the faintest idea *why*. You'll need a grammarian or a linguist for that. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you anyway for your opinion! It has been useful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a phrase begins with a negative adverbial phrase, the interrogative form of the verb is generally used, i.e. "Never in the field of human conflict has so much been owed ..."

Comment: Thank you, that explains it. Have you got any reference?

Comment: The only one I can think of is an English Grammar book, "A Proficiency Course in English", by F.V. Bywater. I get the impression that this book was pre Internet vintage.